# Ubuntu Advantage with Landscape

Tags: landscape, ubuntu-advantage

I've set up a Landscape on-premise server and i've attached a ubuntu 20.04 machine, which is disconnected from internet. I would like to enable UA subscription in order to use ua usg for cis compliance fixes (and maybe ESM in the future), i expected Landscape to give it to the machine automatically, but it doesn't.

Is it possibile to use UA features on disconnected VMs (but with Landscape) ?

Thank you

Comment: As far as I know it doesn't enable them by default.  You might want to see the Landscape tutorials on enabling ua features like the one for ESM:  https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/enable-esm-configurations-at-scale-with-ua-client-and-landscape#1-overview

Comment: problem for me is the "ua attach <your_ua_token>" step. it needs to connect the internet in order to enable it.

Comment: Then it can't be done.  You would need to take this up with Canonical themselves.